# Convert any user input to int in Python

Tags: python

I need to convert user `input` to `int`. Below is what I have written so far which is not working out. It only accepts `int`. the end goal is to have a user inputs float (e.g 4.5) and the output would be (4).

```
i = input("Enter any value: ")

print(int(i))
```

Comment: ```i= float(input("Enter any value: "))

print(int(i))```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Have you actually tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2):

`int` accepts *integer string* or a *float* but cannot handle *float strings*. So convert to *float* first and then convert to *integer*. If the input is invalid format, `int(i)` would raise `ValueError` exception, so you can use it to handle invalid inputs.

```
i = input("Enter any value: ")

try:
  print(float(int(i))
except ValueError:
  print("Please enter a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

The input are in string format so first you need to convert it into float and then from float to int

You can do

```
i = input("Enter any value: ")

print(int(float(i)))
```

or you can do

```
i = float(input("Enter any value: "))

print(int(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers, you can use `round()` function:

```
i = input("Enter any value: ")
print(round(i))
```

But if you want to simply cut the decimal part, you can use math lib and `floor()`:

```
import math
i = input("Enter any value: ")
print(math.floor(i))
```